# Phonegap fileTransfer upload doesn't POST params

Tags: cordova

hope somebody can help me. I'm developing a Phonegap app for iOS and Android that uses the upload method of the Cordova fileTransfer object.

I am uploading audio files with parameters set as follows:

```
var params = {}; 
params.DictionaryEntryID = dictionaryEntryId;
options.params = params;
```

Everything works as it should for iOS - the file is uploaded and the parameters are sent. However on Android, the parameters aren't posted. The file is uploaded and the upload method's success callback is called however.

Can anyone please help. I'm completely stumped on this. I've upgraded to the latest versions of phonegap 2.9.0 to fix this but no luck.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm seeing the same thing with Cordova 3.5